# Onclick em Marker na API do Maps

Tags: javascript, api, maps

Ola, como faço para executar o onclick em um marker do maps?

Meu codigo é este:

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: andando,
    shape: shape,
    title: beach[0],
    html: beach[5],
    zIndex: beach[3]
});
```

no onclick preciso que abra um popUp e passe um valor para o popup, o valor estou recebendo no beach[5].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicando que você já saiba criar popups. Adicione o evento assim e utilize a variável `marker.html`:

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
    /* Aqui você utiliza a variável marker.html */
});
```

Veja a documentação do [GoogleMaps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple?hl=pt-br);

Comment: var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
  icon: andando,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
  html: beach[5],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });
 
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {  
  popupMarker(marker.html);
 });

Comment: não consegui...

Comment: Não conseguiu fazer o evento funcionar ou a popup? Você já possui o código para mostrar a popup ou alguma janela? Se possuir outra parte de código, por favor poste.

Comment: marker.addListener('click', function(){
  window.open('teste.php');
  });

Comment: consegui assim, mas o valor do beach[5] nao consegui passar para o teste.php

Comment: Então sua dúvida é passar a variável para o arquivo `teste.php`. Isso?

Comment: ja consegui, obrigado.